# How to convert seconds to years, months and days

Tags: php

I have found this function to convert seconds to day, months,.. but how to calculate the number of years?

```
function seconds2human($ss) {
   $s = $ss%60;
   $m = floor(($ss%3600)/60);
   $h = floor(($ss%86400)/3600);
   $d = floor(($ss%2592000)/86400);
   $M = floor($ss/2592000);

   return "$M months, $d days, $h hours, $m minutes, $s seconds";
}
```

Comment: function secondsToTime($ss) {

 $M = floor(($ss%31536000)/2592000); // Months
 $Y = floor($ss/31536000);   // Years
 
 if ($Y>0){
  $time .= "$Y years ";
 }
 if ($M>0){
  $time .= "$M months";
 }
 
 $time = empty($time)?"-":$time;
 
 return $time;
}

Comment: here is the answer for the others to know